# How do Redis clients implement pipelining?

Tags: redis

In the Redis [protocol documentation](http://redis.io/topics/protocol) it states:

> A client can use the same connection in order to issue multiple
>   commands. Pipelining is supported so multiple commands can be sent
>   with a single write operation by the client, it is not needed to read
>   the server reply in order to issue the next command. All the replies
>   can be read at the end.

However, I can't find any example of how this is actually implemented. How does a Redis client implement pipelining?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you can easily delimit messages on a TCP stream, little support is really needed for a server to support pipelining, the TCP stack will buffer the data for you, and as a server you can just read/parse requests one-by-one, and send replies back as you finish the requests. The client/server just needs to be aware and handle the cases when these buffers fill up, as to not deadlock.

That said, for redis take a look at processInputBuffer()/processMultibulkBuffer() in networking.c , redis has its own output buffering as well, see e.g. addReply()

Answer (score 6):

Just throwing in some more insights to the above answers. One way to understand redis pipeline is to understand the fact that redis pipeline is completely a client side implementation and the redis server has nothing to do with it. While this differs among different client implementation, here's the generalized idea:

Pipelining is aimed at solving response latency issues in high network latency environments. So, the lesser the amount of time spent over the network in sending commands and reading response, the better. This is effectively achieved by buffering. The client may (or may not) buffer the commands at the TCP stack (as mentioned in other answers) before they are sent to the server. Once they are sent to the server, the server executes them and buffers them on the server side. Unlike the usual case where the client reads the response as soon as the response is received, in case of pipelining, the client reads the responses form the server-side buffer in parts or when the application executes 'sync' (close the pipeline). This is advantageous because the time spent over the network by the client in reading the responses is far lesser.

Here's a post on my blog which you may refer to get a better idea:
http://nachivpn.blogspot.in/2014/11/redis-pipeline-explained.html

Answer (score 5):

A couple good, simple examples of how this is implemented can be found in the source for the Ruby redis client, [redis-rb](http://redis-rb.keyvalue.org/v2.2.0), and one of Python's, [redis-py](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py), respectively listed below.

They do essentially what TaylorOtwell mentioned above, concatenate client-side the requests that will be made to redis in a pipeline into a single network request, whereas transactions would use the redis commands `MULTI`/`EXEC` to begin and end a transaction.

**redis-rb** (from [redis.rb](https://github.com/ezmobius/redis-rb/blob/master/lib/redis.rb) and [pipeline.rb](https://github.com/ezmobius/redis-rb/blob/master/lib/redis/pipeline.rb)):

```
def pipelined(options = {})
  synchronize do
    begin
      original, @client = @client, Pipeline.new
      yield
      if @client.commands.empty?
        []
      else
        original.call_pipelined(@client.commands, options)
      end
    ensure
      @client = original
    end
  end
end

def call_pipelined(commands, options = {})
  @commands.concat commands
  nil
end
```

Another good example can be found in the source for [redis-py](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/blob/74d4666a4190541ee11da3ec629a60b9b1ce6d9d/redis/client.py), a Python redis client. Hope that helps.